# Could not create SSL/TLD secure channel in Docker build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, tls1.2

I have a Docker build script that functions just fine on a local machine but fails on my build server with the error "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." This happens when trying to retrieve an archive from a resource using TLS 1.2.

The download works just fine from the command line on the local machine; the trouble is in the Docker Windows image.

Here's what I've added to my Dockerfile in an attempt to get around this:

- RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
- RUN "Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord;"

No matter what I do, when I run RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol; in my Dockerfile I'm told that the only available protocols are Ssl3 and Tls, not Tls12.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but the RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12; is lost when the RUN command is finished. You need to include that in the same RUN for example:

```
RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 ; `
Invoke-WebRequest "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$env:NUGET_VERSION/nuget.exe" -UseBasicParsing -OutFile "$env:ProgramFiles\NuGet\nuget.exe"
```

Comment: #Install Chocolatey
RUN [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

Comment: See also my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75163583/120603

Answer (score 0):

**Add this sigle line in a Dockerfile having a window base image**

```
RUN Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force                                             
RUN [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol ; \ 
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 ; \
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.ps1 -OutFile installcredprovider.ps1; \
.\installcredprovider.ps1 ; \
del installcredprovider.ps1
```